# React & Browserify: Do I have options for lazy loading?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lazy-loading, browserify

I am using React 15.6 and Browserify with a Ruby and Node backend. My homepage is rather bloated and I'd like to lazy load the images below the fold.
 All the options I am coming across for lazy loading have webpack as a dependency.  Are there any simple solutions that don't require webpack?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the new React v16.6.0 feature [React Lazy](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)

> React.lazy takes a function that must call a dynamic import(). This
>   must return a Promise which resolves to a module with a default export
>   containing a React component.

Example:

```
const LazyImageComponent = React.lazy(() => import('./LazyImageComponent'));

function MyComponent() {
  return (
    <div>
      <LazyImageComponent  />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: using React 16.0 or higher is not really an option right now.  I am using createClass, which is deprecated and removed from 16.0 and higher